# How to use QGIS3 Authentication Manager to authenticate hundreds of users?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

Has anyone used QGIS3 Authentication Manager to handle hundreds of users?  What is the best way to implement role based access for QGIS3?  We are loading layers from PostgreSQL 10.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS's Authentication Manager is essentially just a client-side password store. It's not an authentication provider, s you don't authenticate hundreds of users with it.

Treat this as a database admin problem, not a QGIS problem.

Manage your roles on the PostgreSQL database server and give access there to tables, schemas, databases, read or write, as however fits your purposes. This way you can use PostgreSQL's integrations with LDAP, Kerberos, etc… to integrate with your organisation's existing infrastructure. Then every person using QGIS can just set up their own PostGIS connections in the browser panel or the data source manager using their own already known credentials.

Comment: What about using SSO? Is that possible with the configuration manager? I have searched high and low and have not found a solution. If I'm deploying qgis in a company I wasn't to preconfigured the access so users don't have to all set up the same thing. If they alry are authenticated in the database and just the token from their windows login, how can that be achieved? I think that is what the OP is seeking clarification and, and so am I.

Comment: What about using SSO? Is that possible with the configuration manager? I have searched high and low and have not found a solution. If I'm deploying qgis in a company I wasn't to preconfigured the access so users don't have to all set up the same thing. If they alry are authenticated in the database and just the token from their windows login, how can that be achieved? I think that is what the OP is seeking clarification and, and so am I.